# How does a UIButton store the different UI states

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I was looking into adding a `UILabel` property into a `UIButton` as a subview, matching the functionality of the `titleLabel` property currently present, and giving it all the different states of the button (`UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateHighlighted`, etc.).

I started playing around with storing the states in a `NSDictionary` using the state (wrapped in a `NSNumber`) as the key to the dictionary with the values being the text, text colour and shadow colour. But I'm not sure this would work correctly based on the various different button state combinations.

So far I've got a the following methods:

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    super.selected = selected;

    [self stateUpdated];
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    super.highlighted = highlighted;

    [self stateUpdated];
}

-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    super.enabled = enabled;

    [self stateUpdated];
}

-(void)stateUpdated
{
    [self updateValueLabel];
}

-(void)setValueText:(NSString *)text forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    NSMutableDictionary *stateValues = self.customStates[@state];

    // If we haven't set the state before create a new place to store them
    if (!stateValues) {
        stateValue = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.customStates[@state] = stateValues;
    }

    if (text) {
        stateValues[@"text"] = text;
    } else {
        [stateValues removeObjectForKey:@"text"];
    }

    [self updateValueLabel];
}

-(void)setValueTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor forState:(UIControlState)state
{
    NSMutableDictionary *stateValues = self.customStates[@state];

    // If we haven't set the state before create a new place to store them
    if (!stateValues) {
        stateValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.customStates[@state] = stateValues;
    }

    if (text) {
        stateValues[@"textColor"] = textColor;
    } else {
        [stateValues removeObjectForKey:@"textColor"];
    }

    [self updateValueLabel];
}

-(void)updateValueLabel
{
    NSMutableDictionary *currentStateValues = self.customStates[@self.state];

    // Set the new values from the current state
    self.valueLabel.text = currentStateValues[@"text"];
    self.valueLabel.textColor = currentStateValues[@"textColor"];
}
```

I have the `valueLabel` as a property on the `UIButton` subclass.

The different attributes set for the different states don't seem to be taking effect. If I set them all manually with different bitmasks its fine, but I want to emulate the default fallback states as `UIButton` does for its properties.

So instead of having to set each one manually:

```
[button setValueText:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setValueText:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateHighighted];
```

I want to be able just to set the title once:

```
[button setValueText:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And it show for all states.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a getter `valueTextForState:`, like Apple does with [`titleForState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW11). The documentation for this method's return value reads:

> The title for the specified state. If no title has been set for the specific state, this method returns the title associated with the UIControlStateNormal state.

So, let's do this as well for your property:

```
- (NSString *)valueTextForState:(UIControlState)state
{
    NSString *result;
    NSDictionary *currentStateValues;

    currentStateValues = self.customStates[@(state)];
    result = currentStateValues[@"text"];

    if (!result && state != UIControlStateNormal) {
        // Fall back to normal state.
        currentStateValues = self.customStates[@(UIControlStateNormal)];
        result = currentStateValues[@"text"];
    }

    return result;
}
```

You would do the same for your color. Then your `updateValueLabel` would look like this:

```
-(void)updateValueLabel
{
    // Set the new values from the current state
    self.valueLabel.text = [self valueTextForState:self.state];
    self.valueLabel.textColor = [self valueColorForState:self.state];
}
```

Comment: I should have probably put that `valueTextForState:` method in my question as I actually already had it. Acutally I've also got a `currentValueText` which matches the `UIButton` methods. I'm just not sure if I can do the whole, "Fall back to normal state" as what happens with the other states - do they all have different fallback states or do they all use `UIControlStateNormal`? I just hoped there was a nicer way without setting specific fallbacks.

Comment: Oh I completed skiped over the quote of the apple docs - went straight for the code! Sorry! That answers my question perfectly. Thanks! :)

Comment: Oh though annoyingly [`titleShadowColorForState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleShadowColorForState:) and [`titleColorForState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/titleColorForState:) don't seem to mention a default value! :( Oh well, I'll just match the other ones

Comment: One more thing! There's a small typo:
`currentStateValues = self.customStates[@self.state];`
should be
`currentStateValues = self.customStates[@state];`

Thanks again!

Comment: @Rich: You're right, and I've seen that your edit was incorrectly rejected as the reviewers didn't bother thinking. I've fixed it.